# How to add more words into wordcloud R package that can be excluded in the output?

Tags: r, word-cloud, r-package

I'm using package "wordcloud" with description "Word Cloud" from the R Packages repository. When I create wordcloud from some random text, some words are omitted automatically as they should not be a part of wordcloud. Now, I want to add more words like "this" and "that" to the package so they get excluded from wordcloud as well.

Currently, these words are being excluded from text: "is, to, be, I, not, a, of, out, but, who, here, how, in, some, so, that, it, because, against, Oh, by"

Comment: You could improve your question. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve it accordingly. Or at least respect that for future postings. A good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session.

Comment: I will keep this in mind from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to many words to be removed, you can do

```
set.seed(1)
library(wordcloud)
stopwords <- c("my", "foo", "buzz")
txt <- "hello world. hello my world again. Foo bar fizz buzz."
clean <- gsub(paste(stopwords, collapse="|"), "", txt, ignore.case = TRUE)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
wordcloud(txt)
wordcloud(clean)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you look at a new question I just asked? it is somewhat similar to this one. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921598/how-to-remove-words-from-wordcloud-r-package-so-that-they-can-be-included-in-the)