# How to remove words from wordcloud R package so that they can be included in the output?

Tags: r, word-cloud, r-package

I'm using package "wordcloud" with description "Word Cloud" from the R Packages repository. When I create wordcloud from some random text, some words are omitted automatically as they should not be a part of wordcloud.

Code:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(NLP)
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)


wordcloud("foo bar oh oh by by bye bingo hell no", scale=c(3,1), colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"),random.order=FALSE)
```

Output:

[image: Output of the above mentioned code]

I want to keep words like "oh" and "by" in the wordcloud. How?

Edit: I prefer doing so by removing these words from set of stopwords from wordcloud package, instead of using frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)
txt <- "foo bar oh oh by by bye bingo hell no"
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, control = list(wordLengths = c(-Inf, Inf)))
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
wordcloud(d$word,d$freq,min.freq=1)
```

Comment: Updated the question, now showing preferred method for getting desired output.

Comment: If you enter `wordcloud::wordcloud` you can see that the function uses the `tm` package (`corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords()))`) to remove those words. So you'd have to rewrite the `wordcloud()` function. However, the natural way to use `tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, control = list(wordLengths = c(-Inf, Inf), stopwords = setdiff(tm::stopwords(), c("by", "and"))))` for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use wordcloud():

- one with a string with all the words as the main argument: what you do now
- one with a vector of words and a corresponding vector of frequencies

The first input forces wordcloud() to call tm, constitute a corpus, remove the stopwords and this is the step where you lose the two-letter words.

A simple way is to revert to the use of wordcloud that does not require the tm package, by treating your string before feeding it to wordcloud():

```
library(stringr)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)

## The initial string
mystring <- "foo bar oh oh by by bye bingo hell no"
## Split it and count frequencies
tabl <- table(str_split(mystring,pattern=" "))
## Make the wordcloud: all words are there!
wordcloud(names(tabl),tabl,scale=c(3,1), colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"),random.order=FALSE)
```

Comment: Updated the question, now showing preferred method for getting desired output.

Comment: @JasminShah And why is the proposed solution so bad as to not consider it?

Comment: @Dason, because I need this for specific purpose, so that I can remove words like "out", "but", "who", "here" from the set and see them in the wordcloud. Their amount in any input can differ. With frequency, it applies on every single word, but what if I want it to apply on one or two specific words? I hope I'm making it clear enough.